# XSLT Text output when specific Node exists only

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

For a project im working on i created a stylesheet which works great.

A lot of help from the community, thanks!

Right now im trying to create a text output only when a specific node exists.

For examplme some soil layer data as xml:

```
<NODE1 Name="Well_1" Version="1 ">
  <LAYERS>
    <LAYER>
      <DEPTHTO>1.00</DEPTHTO>
      <INTV>0</INTV>
      <INDEX_ZONE>-1</INDEX_ZONE>
      <REC_CARB_MRKR>2</REC_CARB_MRKR>
    </LAYER>
    <LAYER>
      <DEPTHTO>2.00</DEPTHTO>
      <INTV>0</INTV>
      <INDEX_ZONE>-1</INDEX_ZONE>
    </LAYER>
    <LAYER>
      <DEPTHTO>3.00</DEPTHTO>
      <INTV>0</INTV>
      <INDEX_ZONE>-1</INDEX_ZONE>
      <REC_CARB_MRKR>2</REC_CARB_MRKR>
    </LAYER>
  </LAYERS>
</NODE1>
```

and with that xslt (MSXML 6; xslt1), dont bother some functionalities, its an extract:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes=" xml xsl xs">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template name="REC" match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="WELLCURVE"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="WELLCURVE" match="/*" mode="WELLCURVE">
        <xsl:text>SOME &#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>TEXT &#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Options &#xA;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="LAYERS/LAYER">
            <xsl:variable name="INTVID" select="INTV"/>
            <xsl:variable name="precedingMRKR" select="preceding-sibling::LAYER[INTV = $INTVID][1]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="DEPTHFROM" select="$precedingMRKR/DEPTHTO"/>
            <xsl:if test="INTV=0">
                <xsl:if test="REC_CARB_MRKR != ''">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$precedingMRKR">
                            <xsl:variable name="Layer_mid" select="format-number(((DEPTHTO + $DEPTHFROM) div 2), '0.##')" />
                            <xsl:text>REC </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat($Layer_mid,' ', REC_CARB_MRKR)" />
                            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:variable name="Layer_mid" select="format-number((DEPTHTO div 2), '0.##')" />
                            <xsl:text>REC </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat($Layer_mid,' ', REC_CARB_MRKR)" />
                            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>END_CURVE  &#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>END</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i get that :

```
SOME 
TEXT 
Options 
REC 0.5 2
REC 2.5 2
END_CURVE  
END
```

As you can see "SOME TEXT Options" is always present, no matter if data is present or not (REC_CARB_MRKR node).

So id like to implement some routine, which checkts if in any node "Layer" the Node "REC_CARB_MRKR" exists, and if so, the "SOME TEXT Option" will be needed, also "END CURVE" will ne needed as well. At the moment it works great for some LAYER which do not have data.
But when no LAYER contains REC_CARB_MKRK when the output useless and looks like:

```
SOME 
TEXT 
Options 
END_CURVE  
END
```

In that case the whole xslt block can be ignored, since no data exisits.

Any idea, how to acomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in one possibility:

```
    <xsl:variable name="flagREC_CARB_MRKR" select="boolean(LAYERS/LAYER/REC_CARB_MRKR[1])"/>
    <xsl:if test="$flagREC_CARB_MRKR">
      <xsl:text>SOME &#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>TEXT &#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>Options &#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
```

And you could do this too:

```
   <xsl:if test="$flagREC_CARB_MRKR">
      <xsl:text>END_CURVE  &#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>END</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Hey, it seems to work well, but i dont know exactly why :) Maybe you could tell me, what the "[1]" stands for? I believed first, that it checks the first node only, but my testing shows it works well, even when first node does not contain that node.
Its a little off-topic, but would interest me still. Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: Basically,  I'm setting a variable as a flag.  I did this because you may be using it twice.  So, the flag approach means your document is only searched once.  I used the [1] because only the first REC_CARB_MRKR needs to be found for the flag to be true.  Also, I have a hunch, but no proof, this may be more efficient;  I guess it would depend on which XSLT engine you are using...  The use of boolean returns true or false, whereas, not using it would return the REC_CARB_MRKR node.  But, you don't need the boolean if you are select nodes in and if or when test.  Glad it worked!

Comment: Wow, that was a pretty nice explanation, did help me a lot! Thanks  a lot! I understand it now.